# What is PPC and what does it mean?

Tags: powerpc, ida

So everyone keeps talking about PPC and I don't know what it is. I know that there are multiple terms for PPC, but I know this one is related to a program called Ida or something like that. So please, what does PPC stand for? What does it mean/do? Where can I learn about it?

Comment: Are you referring to the PowerPC architecture (sometimes shortened to PPC)? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC

Comment: you need a context to know what an abbreviation means, you give none.

Answer (score 4):

Given the Google results for 'Ida PPC', I assume what you're looking for is the [PowerPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC) architecture.

Comment: Its somehow related to Xboxes, and bring these hacked jtag xboxes online...

Comment: Then yes, it's PowerPC. It's the processor used in the Xbox, Wii, PS3, and old Macs.

Answer (score 1):

IDA, most likely, stands for [IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/) - a very good piece of disassembler software. PPC, in this context, stands for the [PowerPC processor architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerpc). That's one of the architectures that IDA Pro supports, along with Intel, ARM and many others.